# Gradle build failed android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, windows-10

I am facing the issue below when I build my android project, I have tried invalidating caches and restarting android studio but it did not help - ;

FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':businessProducts:compileDebugLibraryResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 18 exceptions were raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #38: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #39: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #40: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #41: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #42: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #43: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #44: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #45: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #46: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #47: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #48: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #49: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #50: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #51: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #52: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #53: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #54: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #55: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':contactsview:compileDebugLibraryResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 4 exceptions were raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #64: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #66: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #67: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #70: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':avatarbuttons:compileDebugLibraryResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 11 exceptions were raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #56: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #57: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #58: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #59: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #60: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #61: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #62: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #63: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #65: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #68: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #69: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeBetaDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #72: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #71: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #77: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #74: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #73: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #75: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #78: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #76: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Note: I am running windows 10 and there is no official windows universal C runtime available for it. I am also running Android gradle plugin 4.0.0 and gradle version 6.1.1

Comment: This has been resolved, there were security updates applied to my workstation and it was causing this limitation, see my accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this occurs on Windows 10, be sure to first contact your security team. For this specific scenario, some components had been disabled/limited by the security team and this issue was resolved once I got in contact with them.

For Windows 8.1 and below, be sure to first check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62789257/6473807) as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I am running windows 10 and there is no official windows universal C runtime available for it

This? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234

Comment: I have tried downloading those but they do not work on windows 10. Its for windows 8.1 and below.